# Apache Commons Logging implementation differences

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons-logging

I will try to use the Apache Commons Logging to logs in my system. I need some simple, just to keep up on the information and errors, nothing too complex.

I saw that there a lot of implementations there (SimpleLog, AvalonLog, etc.) Someone can explain me the most appropriate or the most complete/full of resources?

Actually I don't know which one to use.

Answer (score 3):

Commons-logging is not a simple logging mechanism. It's a method of allow you to write a library that works regardless of the logging mechanism chosen by someone who incorporates your library.

If you want a simple logging mechanism, just use java.util.logging directly. If you want an even simpler API, use slf4j and then use their 'simple' backend.

You don't need commons-logging unless you have to fit into other people's environments.